# Switching Images in an pictureBox

Tags: .net, winforms

So, i am trying to switch images in an pictureBox. I tried to just switch them with this Code but that just overlaps them

```cs
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     settings1.Show();
     settings1.BringToFront();
     pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.rsz_p_trans_4;
}
```

Since that not worked i am asking here. Any Ideas?

Comment: Add more information.  What language, web or App, what is settings1, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after switching image, try to add this to make sure the image is properly replaced:

```
pictureBox1.Refresh();
await Task.Delay(800);
```

Comment: No. You should **dispose** the last image (if any) and assign the new one. `pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Whatever`. Every time you load an image from `Resources` a new `Bitmap` is created, and when you don't need that `Bitmap` (or any disposable object) any more, you should dispose it. When you do that, the new image will be displayed immediately without needing to call `Refresh();`